# copy cells over multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a yearly planner, containing 53 worksheets.
I populate sheet 1 with weekly tasks, monthly tasks, 3 monthly tasks and 6 monthly tasks.
I then fill the cells :
weekly: blue
monthly : green
3 monthly: yellow
6 monthly : purple

What I want to do is copy the blue cells over all 53 worksheets, into the same cell location
green cells onto every 4th worksheet
yellow onto every 12 worksheet
6 monthly onto every 26th worksheet.

so if cell "c3" was weekly, with blue fill it would be copied over all 53 worksheetsinto cell "c3".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following colors in the following cells:

A1: blue
A2: green
A3: yellow
A4: purple

```
Sub CopyColorsOverSheets()

    Dim lSheetCount As Long

    'Assuming that you start with one sheet in the workbook
    'add the 52 remaining sheets
    For lSheetCount = 2 To 53
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(lSheetCount - 1)
    Next lSheetCount

    'Copy colors over sheets
    For lSheetCount = 2 To 53
        Sheets(1).[A1].Copy Destination:=Sheets(lSheetCount).[A1]
    Next lSheetCount

    For lSheetCount = 2 To 53 Step 4
        Sheets(1).[A2].Copy Destination:=Sheets(lSheetCount).[A1]
    Next lSheetCount

    For lSheetCount = 2 To 53 Step 12
        Sheets(1).[A3].Copy Destination:=Sheets(lSheetCount).[A1]
    Next lSheetCount

    For lSheetCount = 2 To 53 Step 26
        Sheets(1).[A4].Copy Destination:=Sheets(lSheetCount).[A1]
    Next lSheetCount

End Sub
```

Comment: But the problem is the data contained in sheet is extensive, hence the need to copy the sheet and not individual cells, I will aslo end up with over 20 of these planners!

Comment: in your question you wrote that you need to copy cells. you can change the loops to something like this if you want to copy entire sheets:

Sheets(1).Copy after:=Sheets(lSheetCount)